# Dynamic Database connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple client databases that I need to hit on the fly and I am having trouble getting the code I have to work. At first I was just storing a connection string in a clinet object in the db, pulling it out based on logged-in user, and passing it to linq data context constructor. This works fine in my development enviorment but is failing on the Winhost server I am using. It is running SQL 2008. I am getting a "The current configuration system does not support user scoped settings." error.

Any help or guidance on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Greg

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using user-scoped settings, which are stored in the user data path - and you probably don't have permissions for that on the Winhost server.  If this is the case, try switching the scope of your settings to Application (in the project properties) so that they will be stored in the app.config.